# How can I referece the Users application data path in a T4 Template

Tags: t4

How do I reference the Users path in a T4 template.

Nuget packages referenced in .Net Core are downloaded to the users folder (eg: C:\Users\Mark.nuget\packages) I would like to reference/include libraries within a T4 template directly to that folder, is it possible to reference the users folder similar to how we reference the solution folder eg using $(SolutionDir)

Comment: If anyone knows a list of these, please share, I managed to find the answer by trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, $(UserProfile) works